# Navigation with custom renderer of Exoplayer in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, exoplayer

I have a listview in mainpage,when i click listview it goes to 2nd page where it has Exoplayer integration with a custom renderer,so the problem is how to release the player properly,as currently _player is equals to null always ,multiple audios are played,If navigate from first page to 2nd page multiple times.

Here is the code of custom renderer-

```
public class VideoPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoPlayer, SimpleExoPlayerView>, IExoPlayerEventListener
{
    private SimpleExoPlayerView _playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer _player;
    private DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory defaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
    DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory ;
    ExtractorMediaSource extractorMediaSource ;
    public VideoPlayerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }


    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoPlayer> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (_player == null)
        {
            InitializePlayer();
        }


        Play();
    }


    private void InitializePlayer()
    {

        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();

        _player = ExoPlayerFactory.NewSimpleInstance(Context,trackSelector);
        _player.PlayWhenReady = true;
        _playerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(Context) { Player = _player };
        SetNativeControl(_playerView);
        SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
    }

    private void Play()
    {

            Uri sourceUri = Uri.Parse(Element.SourceUrl);
            var mediaUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(Element.SourceUrl);
            var userAgent = Util.GetUserAgent(Context, "App1");
             defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent);
             defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(Context, null, defaultHttpDataSourceFactory);
             extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, defaultDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
            _player.Prepare(extractorMediaSource);
            _player.AddListener(this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom renderer, override `OnDetachedFromWindow` to stop the player:

```
   protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
        _player.Stop();
        _player.Release();
    }
```

Refer: [onDetachedFromWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onDetachedFromWindow())

**Update:**

To control the player, you should create a singleton of `SimpleExoPlayer` , make sure there is only one `_player` in your entire project:

```
class ExoPlayerInstance
{

    private static SimpleExoPlayer _player;

    public static SimpleExoPlayer player
    {
        get
        {
            if (_player == null)
            {
                _player = ExoPlayerFactory.NewSimpleInstance(Application.Context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
                _player.PlayWhenReady = true;
            }
            return _player;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your custom render, remove the `InitializePlayer` part and use the `ExoPlayerInstance`:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoPlayer> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    //remove the InitializePlayer part
    //if (_player == null)
    //    InitializePlayer();

    _player = ExoPlayerInstance.player;

    _playerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(Context) { Player = _player };
    SetNativeControl(_playerView);

    if (_player.IsPlayingAd || _player.IsLoading)
    {
        //maybe something more need to do , stop() here is an example
        _player.Stop();
    }

    Play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,I tried this earlier,but the problem is ,when I click back button of 2nd page the song stops playing,but I want to play the song even though i click in back button or in background,which is fair enough for a audio player

Comment: @uncle_scrooge OK, so what you want is the song is always play until the user pause it or next song is ready to play? You problem now is the two songs play together at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for giving time to this...I just used Android.App.Application.Context instead of context,It is giving excpetion unable to activate instance from native handle...probably due to leaky abstraction..will look into more on your codes

Comment: @uncle_scrooge No problem. I just provide a thought to you. I think use a singleton will lead you to the right way to solve this problem.